# typclass task Haskell flip and fold

Tags: haskell

I have this function.

```
reverse :: (Foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t a)) => t a -> t a
reverse ls = foldr (\l r -> r `mappend` pure l) mempty ls`
```

and now I should turn it into this:

```
reverse::(foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t,a) => t a -> t a)
reverse = foldr (flip _____ . _____ ) ______`
```

I have no clue, I didn't even know that I can leave out the argument (`ls`) in the

`ls = Foldr ...` equation.

So I have no argument for `flip` and no funktion for the point operator.

Flip need 2 arguments and one funktion, I dont see any argument maybe `mempty`.

The dot notation needs 2 funktion and one argument. Maybe i am wrong.

```
reverse::(foldable t, Applicative t, Monoid (t,a) => t a -> t a)
reverse = foldr (flip _____ . _____ ) ______`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

```hs
reverse = foldr (flip mappend . pure) mempty
```

**Long answer**

I think you don't understand one main point - you can apply any function to arguments *"not right away"*.

For example, you can write this:

```hs
f = (+) 5
```

So, function (operator) `+` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, but it doesn't mean that when you want apply `+` you must use two arguments at once. In the example above you defined new object which is function of adding 5.

One more example:

```hs
g = head . tail
```

Although `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, you don't have to pass the last parameter right away. So function `g` has type `[a] -> a`.

Lets' return to your task:

```hs
(\l r -> r ``mappend`` pure l)
```

Rewrite this function:

```hs
(\l r -> mappend r (pure l))
```

```hs
(\l r -> flip mappend (pure l) r)
```

```hs
(\l -> flip mappend (pure l))
```

```hs
(\l -> (flip mappend . pure) l)
```

```hs
flip mappend . pure
```

And you can rewrite

```hs
reverse ls = foldr (flip mappend . pure) mempty ls
```

to

```hs
reverse = foldr (flip mappend . pure) mempty
```